# SOME in T-SQL: how to use it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM VNTREAT WHERE VN = SOME ('482')
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '482'.

Comment: what is SOME? is it a user-defined function?

Comment: no, its part of tsql http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @curtisk: Thanks. Learnt something new today :)

Comment: See also these lesser known functions:   

Macs()  - tells you how many iTards you work with, 

Sealing() - useful in bathrooms, 

Mowed() - determines if lawn cut or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for [`some`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) is to use a subquery.

```
select * from vntreat where vn = some(select '482')
```

In the case of hard-coded values you want to use just `=` or [`in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx):

```
--Get the rows where vn is '482':
select * from vntreate where vn = '482'

--Get any of the rows that have vn equal to '480', '482', or '485'
select * from vntreat where vn in ('480', '482', '485')
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 Cool obscure SQL....Thanks curtisk...

From the links, it appears that SOME operates on series of returned values and can probably be expressed more understandable as 'AT LEAST ONE'... the usage looks similar to 'IN'...

Definitely cool...

Answer (score 1):

Try SELECT * FROM VNTREAT WHERE VN = SOME (Select '482')